# How many routes possible in the traveling salesman problem with $n$ cities? And more...

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, optimization

SO the general answer I come across on the internet is $(n-1)!/2$. But it would seem to be $n!$, or at least $(n-1)!$. Which one is it?

If you have 2 cities, you would have 1 path. So $(n-1)!/2$ can't hold?

EDIT: Another question. Let $P$ be the transition matrix between the routes according to the 2-opt procedure.

> The pairwise exchange or 2-opt technique involves iteratively removing
>   two edges and replacing these with two different edges that reconnect
>   the fragments created by edge removal into a new and shorter tour.

The transition probabilities $P_{kl}$ for given $k$ and $1\leq l \leq size(P)$ can only take two values. What are the two value? I guess $P_{kk} = 0?$

Comment: Is the link http://www.ams.org/samplings/feature-column/fcarc-tsp?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: You are correct; the $(n-1)!/2$ formula holds only for $n\ge 3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So suppose you have $n$ cities, then for any given route, if you remove two edges then you must replace them with their cross matches. For example, lets say you have 
$$A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C\rightarrow D\rightarrow E$$

Then if you remove $(B, C)$ and $(E, A)$ then you *must* replace the with $(B, E)$ and $(A,C)$. This replacement is unequivocal.

So for any pair of edges of a tour there is exactly *one* unequivocal pair of edges as replacement. Furthermore, from every graph of $n$ cities and thus $n$ edges, you can select $$\dfrac{n(n-3)}{2} = \delta$$
pairs of edges which can be replaced by the 2-opt procedure. Why this holds is because, per graph you have the set of all possible pairs of edges *minus* the ones adjacent to each other. So one can not pair $(B,C)$ with $(A,B)$ nor $(C,D)$. Otherwise the 2-opt procedure fails. You divide by two because you have $(A,B) = (B,A)$.

Which brings you to the following: $P_{kl} = \dfrac{1}{\delta}$ if 2-opt possible, if not its 0.

Answer (score 9):

There are $(n-1)!/2$ possible tours in the undirected form of the problem - $(n-1)!$ instead of $n!$ since it doesn't matter which node you start at, and you divide by two since e.g. for three nodes $A, B, C$, the tour $A\to B\to C\to A$ is the same as the tour $A\to C\to B\to A$.

I suppose I should add that in the undirected case, it doesn't really make sense to speak of a traveling salesman tour when $n<3$ since there can't be a cycle in the graph (and that's what a traveling salesman tour is, a Hamiltonian cycle).

Comment: This analysis is sound for $n\ge 3$,  but undercounts when $n\le 2$, which is part of the source of OP's confusion.